# How can I show CircularProgressIndicator() on when method in AsyncData?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-riverpod

I want to show `CircularProgressIndicator()` during loading process with `FutureProvider` and `when() method` as following code. `print("It works");//here` is worked as expected but, `CircularProgressIndicator()` has never been shown at `loading,//here`.
Is my way of using this method wrong or I should fix other things?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:cards/view/register2.dart';
import 'package:cards/view/register4.dart';
import 'package:cards/main.dart';
import 'gender.dart';
import 'header.dart';
import 'navigate.dart';
import 'style.dart';

final authFutureProvider = FutureProvider<bool>(
  (ref) async => authUser(ref),
);

class Register3Widget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authC = ref.watch(authFutureProvider);
    Widget? loading;
    authC.when(
      data: (data) {},
      error: (error, stackTrace) {},
      loading: () {
        print("It works");//here test and actually it worked
        final loading = CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
    final alertMessage = ref.watch(completeErrorMessage);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 75, 20, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 50,
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  child: GenderSelect(),
                ),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        child: MyNavigator(
                          destinationTo: Register2Widget(),
                          context: context,
                          goBack: "back",
                        ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        child: MyNavigator(
                            destinationTo: Register4Widget(),
                            context: context,
                            goBack: "Send Email"),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Align(
                  child: loading,//here
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: alertMessage,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Extracode:

```
    authC.when(
      data: (data) {},
      error: (error, stackTrace) {},
          loading: () {
        final loading = 
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
        );
        });
      },
    );
```

Extracode2:

```
loading: () {
        final loading = 
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
        );
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to return the widget from `loading`

```dart
 loading: () {
        final loading = CircularProgressIndicator();
        return loading; //this
      },
```

Also the top level return, It will be like

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authC = ref.watch(authFutureProvider);
   
    return Scaffold( //here top level return
      body: authC.when(
        data: (data) {
          return Padding(child: ....,);
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) {
          return Text("got Error");
        },
        loading: () {
          final loading = CircularProgressIndicator();

          return loading;
        },
      ),
    );
```

Or just

```dart
                Align(
                  child: authC.when(
                    data: (data) {},
                    error: (error, stackTrace) {},
                    loading: () {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Really thanks for helpful comment. I could understood your code but wonder the part `the top level return`, as I want remain most part of widget and just display `CircularProgressIndicator()` partly.
Your code above seems like `switch` and display "A(success)" or "B(failed)" or "C(loading)".
I actually intend to always display "A" and tapped something and get certain result asynchronously,  show `CircularProgressIndicator()` during loading and finally get the result and display something based on "A".

Comment: Yes, the `.when` method is built like this. If you have a single widget that will be depended on provider, you can include that inside the column.

Comment: thanks a lot and it worked!!! As I mentioned in comment to Raj , If I want show this with showDialog(), I could not deal this as `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` occurred. what's the difference between `CircularProgressIndicator()` and `showDialog` ?

Comment: for this error, you can use `addPostFrameCallback` to show dialog after the frame is build like `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(  (timeStamp) { //dialog});`

Comment: Humm, I did in that way and finally it displayed but never disappeared, even though the loding process completed. Could you please refer my extra code shown above?
Note that, In this case, the showDialog() is not widget which should be included in certain Column, final loading is declared inside when() method instead.

Comment: Once you show a dialog, you need to pop the context to close it based on scenario, you can try  on `data(data){Navigator.of(context).pop();}` .

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you...  How can I use it inside of `loading:` also means during loading. I tried like code Extracode2 but did not work at all.

Comment: You like show dialog on loading and pop on getting data? if so try adding navigator pop as I've shown.

Comment: I've just meant, want showDialog() be shown just during loading. I believe that there are same meanings right ?  So I did like Extracode2 shown above and did not work..

Answer (score 1):

you should use `FutureBuilder` see the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I'll definitely refer the doc and consider if I should use  FutureBuilder instead of FutureProvider. Some people say Its general or prefer to use FutureBuilder than  FutureProvider, and I'm always wondering which to use

Answer (score 0):

```
loading: () {
        print("It works");//here test and actually it worked
loading = CircularProgressIndicator();
//don't declare again
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment and It worked ! It was simple mistake, by the way how can I use showDialog() instead ?  Cause When I rapped `CircularProgressIndicator();` with `showDialog() `,  `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` has occured...